# Jenkins maven build fail in linux machine

Tags: linux, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

My maven command execute fine in windows jenkins server but When i try to execute in linux machine,build got failed

**I have tried Shell command build as belo**w :

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:copy -Dartifact=com.uhg.optum.acc:cores-binaries:%PLATFORM_CORE_VERSION% -DoutputDirectory=. -Dmdep.useBaseVersion=true
```

**Console Output** :

> [EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables. Building remotely on
>   BuildSwarm-6d98547c91e1-apsrp4109.uhc.com (docker-maven-slave) in
>   workspace /home/jenkins/workspace/2.3.0 Deployment Artifacts
>   (QualityMeasures-Platform) [2.3.0 Deployment Artifacts
>   (QualityMeasures-Platform)] $ /bin/sh -xe
>   /tmp/hudson3262693666907249961.sh
>   + mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:copy -Dartifact=com.uhg.optum.acc:cores-binaries:%PLATFORM_CORE_VERSION% -DoutputDirectory=. -Dmdep.useBaseVersion=true /tmp/hudson3262693666907249961.sh: line 2: mvn: command not found
>   Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure Archiving artifacts
>   Finished: FAILURE

Please help me

Comment: has the environment variable %PLATFORM_CORE_VERSION% been set?  If run the command echo $PLATFORM_CORE_VERSION does it return something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your shell script has failed since it can't find maven on this node. Check if you can see the maven installation directory defined on `Manage Jenkins -> System Information` as `M2_HOME` environment variable. You can also check at your terminal using `env` command.

Also `%PLATFORM_CORE_VERSION%` is used to dereference the environment variable under windows, use `$PLATFORM_CORE_VERSION` under Unix machines (as long as it configured)

Comment: Thanks Klein,As u said there no M2_HOME environment variable.